# GAE Server Error when Opening App in Console

Tags: google-app-engine

When I open up the Google App Engine console and click on one particular app I get:-

```
Server Error (500)
A server error has occurred.
```

Additional info:-

- This only happens for one app (I have 8 in total).
- The app is deployed and I can view it no dramas via the appspot URL.
- It happens as soon as I click the app name in the "Applications Overview" page - I am unable to view the console for that app at all.
- There are no errors when deploying from the GAE Launcher and I've tried re-deploying several times.
- I was able to login yesterday morning but have been receiving this error since yesterday afternoon.
- The app is Python (as are all my apps).
- I tried logging in "incognito" and on a different PC without success.
- I also tried deleting all the *.pyc files and re-compiling them but it made no difference.

Has anyone else come across this issue? Any suggestions on how to resolve it?

Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The issue was my YAML file contained:-

```
- url: /.*
  script: about.application
```

Once I changed this so that the "about" page wasn't so greedy, it has worked.